# install app to Sd

Tags: android, app2sd

i want to app to sd,i know in sdk2.2 ,we can install by using xml,but i want to install app to sd in sdk 2.1. at present i only know check version use the code:

```
public static int getSDKVersionNumber() {
     int sdkVersion;
 try {
 sdkVersion = Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK);
 } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
 sdkVersion = 0;
 }
 return sdkVersion;
 }
```

my question:how to install app to sd ,at sdk2.1 and sdk 2.2.
thank you.

Comment: For clarity, I believe you mean API versions 7 and 8 which correspond to Android versions 2.1 and 2.2, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this [resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html) may help you the most.  Install locations should be done through the AndroidManifest.xml file and I believe it was introduced with Android 2.2 (froyo) meaning older phone (2.1 and below) cannot install apps to the SD card.

Resource says:

> The ability for your application to
>   install on the external storage is a
>   feature available only on devices
>   running API Level 8 (Android 2.2) or
>   greater

Bitt Fault, with his app [SDWatch](http://code.google.com/p/sdwatch/) is able to show the user the app setting page. I'm not sure if I'm reading it completely right, but you may able to do it with this code snippet from [NotificationClicked.java](http://code.google.com/p/sdwatch/source/browse/src/com/beaglebros/SDWatch/NotificationClicked.java)

> ```
> Intent oi = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
> oi.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.InstalledAppDetails");
> oi.putExtra("pkg", pkg);
> oi.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
> context.startActivity(oi);
> ```

I'm having a little trouble figuring out what the `String pkg` is exactly though.

Comment: thank you for your reply.yes i know we can use AndroidManifest.xml to install,can we use code to install? and if we can install app at the 2.1?

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to install to SD card at run time.  If there is, its probably discouraged.  The best way I can think to do it would be to direct the user to the app's settings page and have them click the button themselves. And no, devices with 2.1 simple can't install to SD card. I edited my answer slightly for this

Comment: Well I'm a little interested in the problem. A guy named Bitt Faulk is able to show the user the page in his apps

Comment: really,that very well,if he can give some advice?

Comment: I don't know him, I just like his apps. I edited my post again with some more code. I hope I helped :)